# Retrieve and Display Firestore document in Angular 6

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is an Angular 6 and Firestore project. I was attempting to retrieve a single document from Firestore and display its values in the component template.

This code works.

In `article-detail.component.ts`

```
export class ArticleDetailComponent {
  articlesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Article>;
  articles: Observable<Article[]>;
  article: any;
  id: any = 1a3c;

  constructor (private afs: AngularFirestore) {
      this.articlesCollection = this.afs.collection('articles');
      this.articles = this.articlesCollection.valueChanges();

      #### RETRIEVE INDIVIDUAL DOCUMENT HERE #### 
      this.articlesCollection.doc(`${this.id}`).ref.get().then((doc) => {
        this.article = doc.data();
      });
  }
```

In `article-detail.component.html`, display details like so:

```
{{ article.title }}

{{ article.subtitle }}

{{ article.date }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to retrieve and display a Firestore Document in angular.

In `article-detail.component.ts`

```
export class ArticleDetailComponent {
  articlesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Article>;
  articles: Observable<Article[]>;
  article: any;
  id: any = 1a3c;

  constructor (private afs: AngularFirestore) {
      this.articlesCollection = this.afs.collection('articles');
      this.articles = this.articlesCollection.valueChanges();

      #### RETRIEVE INDIVIDUAL DOCUMENT HERE #### 
      this.articlesCollection.doc(`${this.id}`).ref.get().then((doc) => {
        this.article = doc.data();
      });
  }
```

In `article-detail.component.html`, display details like so:

```
{{ article.title }}

{{ article.subtitle }}

{{ article.date }}
```

Comment: Are you sure that ` this.article = doc.data()` working correctly. I m trying such initialization and it gives error `Cannot initialized property of undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should get all values.

Are subtitle and date really there? Subscribe to this.article in ngOnInit and print to the console to check. If you see it in the console, it might be a change detection issue.

Try running manual change detection in a setTimeout after 1 second or after data has been received. Just to see if this is the issue.

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit(){
   this.article.subscribe(data=> {
     console.log(data);
     this.cd.detactChanges(); 
   }
}
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tymujv)